# ReactJS: How do I open an Material-UI Accordion programmatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, accordion

The Accordions all have an id:

```
const CategoryDisplay: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
...
  return (
    <>
      <Accordion
        id={`category-${accordion.id}`}/>
    </>
  );
};

export default CategoryDisplay;
```

And I've got a function that finds a specific Accordion with an id via a hash value in the link and scrolls to it:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const anchor = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];
  if (anchor) {
    const anchorEl = document.getElementById(anchor);
    if (anchorEl) {
      anchorEl.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
}, []);
```

Now I also want to expand that specific accordion. How would I go about this for Material-UI accordions? I'd have to set expanded on the anchorEl somehow.

Comment: Why do you want to use the id to expand your accordion ? You can just controlled it with a state

Comment: Go to the Material-UI Accordion documentation, look for any means to manipulate its collapsed state from the outside, most likely a property `isCollapsed` or similar, write your code to set that property accordingly whenever you want to collapse or open the accordion programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Accordion has `expanded` prop. Set it to `true` and Accordion will expand:

```
const CategoryDisplay: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
const [expand, setExpand] = useState(new Array(numberOfAccordions).fill(false)) 
...
  return (
    <>
      <Accordion
        id={`category-${accordion.id}`} expanded={expand[accordion.id]}/>
    </>
  );
};

export default CategoryDisplay;

useLayoutEffect((accordionId) => {
  const anchor = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];
  if (anchor) {
    const anchorEl = document.getElementById(anchor);
    if (anchorEl) {
      let result = [...expand];
      result[accordionId] = true;
      setExpand(result);
      anchorEl.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: the name of the property in the code should be `expanded` and not `expand`